# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jquery@>=3.0.0 & popper.js@^1.11.0

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4, popper.js

While installing Bootstrap 4 (the latest beta version) with NPM : `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta, I got this message :

```
+-- bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
+-- font-awesome@4.7.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jquery@>=3.0.0
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY popper.js@^1.11.0

npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0-beta requires a peer of jquery@>=3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0-beta requires a peer of popper.js@^1.11.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN b4starter@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

To remove this warning : `npm i --save jquery popper.js`

But, why the first command didn't install Bootstrap 4, Jquery and Popper.js in one time? normally NPM should install dependencies !!

Any explaination please?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

The problem was reported to the Bootstrap development team in [**this issue**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24078). In principle, Bootstrap 4 can be used [without jQuery and Popper](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/#compiled-css-and-js), but these two optional packages are considered as peer dependencies in the bootstrap@4.0.0-beta version installed with npm.

According to the comments made by the Bootstrap developers in the discussion, they are going to offer two different Bootstrap packages:

- bootstrap-css: which will not have any dependency on jQuery and Popper
- bootstrap: which, I assume, will install the required dependencies

Comment: That problem goint to resolve, will be resolve with `npm install --save jquery popper.js`

Answer (score 2):

All depend of the configuration of the package.json from the npm package.
if you check the respository for [bootstrap here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/7b715ee7e846d0e53d9839b91254676f3795f3bd/package.json#L76), you can see this:

```
...
"dependencies": {},
"peerDependencies": {
 "jquery": "^3.0.0",
 "popper.js": "^1.12.3"
},
...
```

When you install a npm package, just the dependencies specified in package.json file as dependencies would be download with the package.

If you want to know more about `peerDependecies` this is the link: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies